# How to guarantee the order of multiple ajax results?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a ajex request with ".done()" and calling it multiple times and want to make sure the process in done() is processed in order. Not sure how much time the process in done() will take. It could be 0.1 sec or could be 0.5 sec.

Simple example:
Let's say I have a reuqest button here and click it 5 times. It will send 1-5 number to server in order then echo it. There is sleep() in done() to simulate the delay. Is there a way to echo 1-5 in order as a result?

```
<button id="test">Request</button>

var counter = 0;
$(function(){
    $('#test').on('click',function(){
        counter++;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'echo.php', // Simply echo back argument (counter value)
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"counter":counter}
        }).done(function(data){
            // Simulate delay
            let waitsec = Math.floor(Math.random()*(3-1)+1);
            sleep(waitsec, function() {
                console.log(data);　// show 1-5
            });
        });
    });
});

function sleep(waitSec, callback) {
  var spanedSec = 0;
  var waitFunc = function () {
      spanedSec++;
      if (spanedSec >= waitSec) {
          if (callback) callback();
          return;
      }
      clearTimeout(id);
      id = setTimeout(waitFunc, 1000);
  };
  var id = setTimeout(waitFunc, 1000);
}
```

**Edited:** Based on the advice from Afonso. I modified the code. It now stores request parameters in array and run one by one after done. It still does not work propery. What's wrong with my code?

```
var counter = 0;
var jqxhr;
var jqxhr_requests = [];
$(function(){
    $('#test').on('click',function(){
        counter++;
        console.log("c: "+counter)
        let request = {
            url: 'echo.php', // Simply echo back argument (counter value)
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"counter":counter},
        };

        if(jqxhr_requests.length <= 0) // Run first request
        {
            jqxhr_requests.push(request);
            jqxhr = $.ajax(jqxhr_requests[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            jqxhr_requests.push(request);
        }

        jqxhr.done(function(data) {
            // Simulate delay
            let waitsec = Math.floor(Math.random()*(3-1)+1);
            sleep(waitsec, function() {
                console.log(data);
            });
            jqxhr_requests.shift();
            jqxhr = $.ajax(jqxhr_requests[0]);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate if a request was already done before you do an ajax request again. If it is still waiting for a response, you can save in an array the data you want to send to server, and when .done() its called, check the data you have in the array and then do the ajax request with that data.